# Make VS Code read GitHub Actions file references (file=foo.txt,line=123)

Tags: visual-studio-code

It would be great if VS Code could understand the file reference created for GitHub Actions:

```
> make lint

...
golangci-lint run --out-format=github-actions
::error file=foo.go,line=754::File is not `gofumpt`-ed with `-extra` (gofumpt)
```

Is there a way to make VS Code open the file `foo.go` at line `754` somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. You could either write or find a VS Code extension that provides this feature, or you could ask VS Code to make this a builtin feature. I guess another option would be to ask politely if an existing extension would be willing to implement this feature.

The main VS Code extension API of interest is [`TerminalLinkProvider<TerminalLink>`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TerminalLinkProvider%3CT%3E).

From a quick scan of the [`GitHub.vscode-github-actions`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.vscode-github-actions) extension, it seems like they don't implement this, but it might be worth [asking them if they'd be willing to](https://github.com/github/vscode-github-actions/issues/new?assignees=&labels=enhancement&projects=&template=feature_request.md&title=).

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.